# Connect an electronic drum kit to a powered speaker

Tags: amplifiers, drums, cable, stage-setup

I have a Behringer B112D (powered PA speaker) for my son's drum kit (a ddrum DD1Plus).

The drum head has separate 1/4" jacks for output, L/mono and R (I'm assuming those are TS outputs?) and a 1/4" phone jack (for headphones, which should be TRS stereo out). The owner's manual for the ddrum doesn't give much information about the outputs though, but it does show a picture showing two amplifiers, each connected to a single output jack. The powered speaker has two 1/4" TRS (servo-balanced) jacks (labeled as Line/Mic) and a two-channel mixer built-in.

I see a few different options for connecting everything together:

1. Two TRS cables from the DD1Plus into both input jacks on the B112D. So that would give me one from the L output into one input and one from the R output into the other input, letting the built-in mixer in the speaker combine them together.
2. A single cable TS from the L/Mono output on the DD1Plus to a single input on the B112D.
3. A Y-splitter to take the L and R outputs on the DD1Plus into one TRS cable into a single input on the B112D.
4. A single TRS cable from the phone jack on the DD1Plus to a single input on the B112D.

What's the "right" way to connect everything (so it has the best sound output with the least amount of noise from interference or ungrounded inputs)?

For ease of reference, in case anyone wants/needs details on the equipment:

- B112D: https://mediadl.musictribe.com/media/PLM/data/docs/P0AJN/B115D_B112D_WebBrochure.pdf
- DD1Plus: https://www.ddrum.com/images/manuals/DD1%20Plus%20manual.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a mono speaker.

The DD1+ has a mono output.

So, connect the DD1+ L/mono Out to one of the Line inputs of the B112D.

The speaker will accept a balanced input on a TRS plug.    It's unclear whether the drums offer a balanced output.   A TS-TS cable will work.    If you HAVE a TRS-TRS cable try that too.  There's a slight possibility you'll get more signal and less hum.  But if the TS-TS sounds fine, don't fuss!

Note that the speaker accepts a wide range of levels. When feeding it a Line signal the volume control isn't MEANT to go beyond half-way.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one channel available on the powered speaker. So doing *anything* 'stereo' is a waste. You have L/mono out of the drum brain. That sums it all together. Use that, and plug into one channel of the Behringer. One signal in, one signal out. Simple, and using the simplest plug arrangement - mono to mono.

To make it sound *really* good, get another Behringer, and use it as the other channel. It will make a big difference. Or stick to using cans, which sound great, and won't annoy anyone...

Comment: Or if you want it to sound really really good get a big subwoofer too...wait, that will be even louder than a real drum set!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have one speaker and the Behringer L output doubles as a mono output (L/mono) use choice “2”. All you need is a single mono 1/4” instrument cable. The drum machine will output a mono signal if nothing is connected to the right output and a TRS type cable is not necessary since it is a mono output.